# qml how to keep focus on TextField

Tags: qt, keyboard, qml, focus, textfield

I want to keep focus on TextField. For example i am typing something then tap to button. The focus on TextField is moving to button, that's why keyboard is automatically hiding on Android. I am using Qt 5.9.2. Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: "i am typing something then tap to button". Is it the New Line button that you are typing when the focus switches?

Comment: @DorinBotan This button sends the message i typed.

Comment: It is just frustrating send 1 message, keyboard is automatically hiding, then tap to TextField showing keyboard then send second message.

Comment: Strangely, in an older version of Qt I had the opposite problem - keyboard was not hiding. I solved that by doing smth. like `Keys.onEnterPressed: Qt.inputMethod.hide()` in my QML TextField. Can you do the opposite and just pop the keyboard back when it hides?

Comment: Yes i did back focus to TextField and displaying keyboard, but this moment app blinking. I mean keyboard hiding and showing, it is actually so good.

Comment: Are you using Qt Quick Controls 1 or 2?

Comment: @Mitch Thank you for your response! I am using QtQuick.Controls 2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Qt Quick Controls 2, each control has a `focusPolicy` property which determines how the control gets focus. The default for controls like `Button` is `Qt.StrongFocus`, which means that buttons get focus after being clicked or tabbed into. If you're seeing that a control has focus and you don't want it to, just set its `focusPolicy` to `Qt.NoFocus`:

```
focusPolicy: Qt.NoFocus
```